# Font awesome icons not displayed with ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-awesome

I have a web server running on linux Redhat with apache.
My server hosts the 'font awesome' fonts.

When requesting the web pages from another computer, if Chrome is used the icons are correctly displayed. If ie9 is used the icons are not displayed. 
If the 'font awesome' page is opened with ie9 or chrome, the icons are correctly displayed.
I read other posts, I changed the @font_face, I still can not manage to display the icons of my pages with ie9?

Any ideas where to look?

Thank you

Ben

Comment: Make sure you have the font awesome general class and the specific icon. E.g. `class="fa fa-home"`

Comment: I have the font and working fine with Chrome. And I do not understand why the 'font awesome' website displayed the icons correctly in ie9, but not my website (hosted on my server).

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem. It was a wrong declaration in the DOCTYPE tag, just put DOCType html and it worked out.

in case this problem occurs to you, use the 'font awesome' web page as a reference and compare with your page.
I copied the 'font awesome' page and modified to check against my page.

Comment: A slight note to this: you should ALWAYS declare a proper DOCTYPE - plenty of small issues pop up if one is not set.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  }
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #545454;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
ul li a:hover {
  color: #C86565;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>Habitath</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Habitath a online coach hiring website" />
<meta name="keywords" content="habitath, ecosystem, online coach website" />
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Squada+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer would be easier to evaluate if there was some commentary/description to explain what it does and how. Could you please [edit] it and add it? Thank you!

Comment: Use the link above and supports the iE9